# Continuous Vibration Without cutoff in Android

Tags: android, vibration

I am working with a project which needs the phone vibrates continuously without breaking in any moment.
This is the piece of code used by me.

Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

long[] pattern = {0,200,0}

vibe.vibrate(pattern,0);

but this code is not suiting my requirement as it cuts off for a small milli second. (This is for a hardware project where using the signal from the vibrator to keep the bluetooth on in full swing and the voltage drop during cut off makes the bluetooth to restart).

Comment: You could specify the vibration for a very long time in milliseconds.

Comment: i have done that but no use the vibration breaks(for a small milli second) at a certain time.

Comment: Is it for all devices or for a particular device?

Comment: i checked it with only a particular device. I will check with other devices.